# How to combined several dependent centered (z scores) variables in a ggplot to produce a kind of a forest plot describing all of the result

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, visualization

let's say I want to have 2 or 3 dependent variables (all centered) in a ggplot without having to create a dataset combining the outcomes.

Therefore, instead of having a plot for one outcome
[image: Math]

and a plot for another outcome
[image: science]

I would like to have *in the sample plot* both results (math and science) without the need of using `bind_rows` to combine them. That's the solution I can produce, but with tons of unnecessary coding, I guess.

[image]

I'm following an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77903162/draw-a-common-vertical-line-to-two-plots-with-r-patchwork-and-probably-grid-pa) and I would like to

That's the code

```
library(tidyverse)
df2 = data.frame(
  zscore_math = rnorm(120,0,1),
  zscore_science = rnorm(120,0,2),
  grade = c("6","7","8"),
  sex = c("m","f")
)

# Independent plots

df2 %>%
  pivot_longer(c(grade, sex))  %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = value, y =  zscore_science )) +
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_cl_boot,geom = "errorbar") +
  stat_summary(fun.data=mean_se,color = "navy", geom = "point", size=2) +
  facet_grid(name~., space = "free", scale = "free", switch = "y") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, color = "darkslategray3", linetype = 2) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank()
    
  ) 

# Combined plot
bind_rows(
  
  df2 %>%
    select(zscore_math, grade, sex) %>% 
    pivot_longer(c(grade, sex))   %>%
    mutate(domain = "math") %>%
    rename(result = zscore_math ),
  
  df2 %>%
    select(zscore_science, grade, sex) %>% 
    pivot_longer(c(grade, sex))   %>%
    mutate(domain = "science") %>%
    rename(result = zscore_science ),
  
  
) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = value, y =  result, color = domain )) +
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_cl_boot,geom = "errorbar", position = position_dodge(0.7) ) +
  stat_summary(fun.data=mean_se,geom = "point", position = position_dodge(0.7),
               size=1) +
  facet_grid(name~., space = "free", scale = "free", switch = "y") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, color = "darkslategray3", linetype = 2) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank()
    
  )
```

Comment: Except for the typo `eom=` which should be `geom=` your code works fine. Could you clarify what's exactly the issue with your code and/or the result?

Comment: Yes. Instead of using the `bind_rows` argument, I would like to produce the same combined plot.

Comment: If you want to get rid of `bind_rows` you could use another `pivot_longer`,e.g. `df2 %>% pivot_longer(-c(grade, sex), names_prefix = "zscore_", names_to = "domain", values_to = "result") %>% pivot_longer(c(grade, sex)) %>% ...`

Comment: Amazing. That's the final code.  If you answer my question, I'll upvote you.

Comment: `df2 %>% pivot_longer(-c(grade, sex), names_prefix = "zscore_", names_to = "domain", values_to = "result") %>% pivot_longer(c(grade, sex)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = value, y =  result, color = domain )) +stat_summary(fun.data = mean_cl_boot,geom = "errorbar", position = position_dodge(0.7) ) +
  stat_summary(fun.data=mean_se,geom = "point", position = position_dodge(0.7),
               size=1) +
  facet_grid(name~., space = "free", scale = "free", switch = "y") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, color = "darkslategray3", linetype = 2) +
  coord_flip() `